# Boto3 DynamoDB update list attributes for an item

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a table like:

```
{
"pKey": 10001,
"items": [
    {
        "name": "A",
        "value": 100
    },
    {
        "name": "B",
        "value": 100
    }
]
}
```

I would like to update all `value` attributes in `items` list to be 200, `items` list can have 1 to n objects.

How can I do that using boto3 python dynamoDB low-level client APIs?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't really tested this but this is what I can come up just by reading the [docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html):

```
import boto3

ddb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = ddb.Table('your_table')

document = table.get_item(Key={'pKey': 10001})['Item']

for item in document['items']:
    item['value'] = 200

table.put_item(Item=document, ReturnValues='NONE')
```

Comment: Appreciate this simple solution. However, I wonder if the `get_item` + `put_item` cost the same as `update_item` API, since I have potentially billions of entries need to be updated. This seems like rewrite all of them, it can cost a lot.

Comment: Works great for me.